# How can I migrate a Linux installation from HDD to SSD?

Tags: linux, system-installation, disk-image

I have some normal x86_64 desktop Linux installed in a single ext4 root partition<sup>†</sup> on some 500GB HDD.

Now if I want to migrate this installation to a 500GB SSD (rest of the system stays the same), do I just clone the disk and run `genfstab` (I know that from the Arch installation guide, do I even need that?) and done?

Or is there more to it?

---

<sup>†</sup>That is, *everything* is in that single partition. I do not have a swap partition, but a swap file, and my system can easily do without that too if it should be an issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research, I found that ext4 is apparently quite usable on SSDs, so I went with the clone approach. Here is what I did, step by step:

1. Install the SSD
2. Boot from a USB and clone the HDD to SSD with `dd`
3. **Change the UUID of the new filesystem**. I missed that one at first, which caused funny results as `grub` and other software got confused
4. Update the `fstab` on the new filesystem. I used the `genfstab` script from the Arch USB for that
5. Re-generate `initramfs`, reinstall and reconfigure `grub`
6. Move SSD to the top in boot priority, done

The above worked for me; however, I am very much a novice admin, so I'm not sure if every step is actually necessary and useful.

Comment: What if your HDD is bigger than your new SSD?

Comment: @JasonStack You cannot just clone the disk then afaict. See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/q/409204

Comment: Can I just clone /boot and /?

Comment: @JasonStack If you have sufficiently large target partitions, I guess so? However, as I said before, I'm not good at that admin business, you might want to ask a new question for that to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **but...**

yes, you can simply clone/copy the HDD content in the new SSD, because an SSD is a disk, just as an HDD.
**but** also SSD is a completely different technology, so you have to adjust swap partition and discard setting.

Anyway, I suggest you a clean install

Comment: I don't use a swap partition, but a swap file. The entire installation lives in a single partition. I'll try to clarify that in my question.

Comment: *"but also SSD is a completely different technology"* Swap aside, what are the potential issues with that?

Comment: TRIM support mainly and you can choose a file-system SSD friendly

Comment: That's an interesting point, thanks. I'll look into that.

Comment: That file-system argument appears to be important, I guess I probably want btrfs now or smth. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/file-system-for-an-ssd-drive